# Delphi - HWND to listbox

Tags: delphi

i wanna read text from another window and get it on a listbox on my form.

see the code below, i get the room classes of the text but i dont know how i can covert it
to listbox

```
procedure TForm1.GetNicksBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  hWnd1 :long;
  CheckMsg :String;
begin
  CheckMsg := '1'; //convert it to 0 to you can check the FindWindowEx

  hWnd1 := FindWindow('DlgGroupChat Window Class',Pchar(cbPalWindows.Text));
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('1');
  Exit;

   hWnd1 := FindWindowEx(hWnd1,0,'SplitterWindowEx',nil);
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('2');
  Exit;

  hWnd1 := FindWindowEx(hWnd1,0,'SplitterWindowEx',nil);
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('3');
  Exit;

  hWnd1 := FindWindowEx(hWnd1,0,'SplitterWindowEx',nil);
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('4');
  Exit;

  hWnd1 := FindWindowEx(hWnd1,0,'SplitterWindowEx',nil);
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('5');
  Exit;

  hWnd1 := FindWindowEx(hWnd1,0,'SplitterWindowEx',nil);
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('6');
  Exit;

  hWnd1 := FindWindowEx(hWnd1,0,'ClassCPaneContainerEx',nil);
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('7');
  Exit;

  hWnd1 := FindWindowEx(hWnd1,0,'ATL:00AD6100',nil);
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('8');
  Exit;

  hWnd1 := FindWindowEx(hWnd1,0,'ATL:00AD65E0',nil);
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('9');
  Exit;

  hWnd1 := FindWindowEx(hWnd1,0,'AtlAxWin90',nil);
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('10');
  Exit;

  hWnd1 := FindWindowEx(hWnd1,0,'#32770',nil);
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('11');
  Exit;

  hWnd1 := FindWindowEx(hWnd1,0,'RichEdit20W',nil);
  if (hWnd1 = 0) and (CheckMsg = '0') then //for test purposes
  showmessage('12');
  Exit;

  if hWnd1 <> 0 then
  Begin
  End;

end;
```

This is the code written on VB how i can do it on delphi ?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim iHnd8 As Long
If iHnd8 <> IntPtr.Zero Then
Dim NicArray() As String = mdlSysListView.GetAllSLVItems(iHnd8)
Debug.Print(NicArray.Length.ToString)
For i = 0 To NicArray.Length - 1
ListBox1.Items.Add(NicArray(i))
Next
ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Total # of Nics in room is - " & ListBox1.Items.Count)
End If
```

Comment: Your code does effectively nothing. It attempts to get handle of a "DlgGroupChat Window Class" window and exits the method. I suppose this is [`your question`](http://www.imfiles.com/get-all-room-nicknames-t44148/), so to be complete, here is the [`GetAllSLVItems`](http://pastebin.com/meUxyGNn) method. Good luck!

Comment: @TLama - so the OP's real question is, 'how do I translate this custom VB.NET routine (`GetAllSLVItems`) into Delphi Pascal'...?

Comment: @Chris, I would say yes, since there is not much to add to the list box from that Delphi code.

Comment: OP - assuming @TLama is correct, I reckon you should accept David Heffernan's answer and start a new question with the bits of `GetAllSLVItems` you are struggling to translate (it translates more or less directly, though could be cleaned up a little bit too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read the content of a list view control in another process. This is not trivial because it involves the LVM_GETITEMTEXT message which requires you to pass a pointer to memory allocated in the address space of the target process.

In order to meet that requirement you need to do the following:

1. Find the process ID of the target process.
2. Call OpenProcess to get a process handle.
3. Call VirtualAllocEx to allocate the memory for an LVITEM struct in the other process.
4. Use WriteProcessMemory to initialize the struct.
5. Send the control the LVM_GETITEMTEXT message.
6. Read the contents of the struct using ReadProcessMemory.

It's quite tricky to get right and does require you to have a very clear understand of many different aspects of Win32 programming.

The canonical tutorial is here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/int64_memsteal.aspx

Now, a much better way to do this, in both VB and Delphi, would be to use the Automation API, assuming that the target application supports this.